# Swift Algorithm : how to get String that includes all substrings without repetition

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

Suppose you get an input like below:

hello
helloSwift
Swi
Apple
le

(total 5)

I want a function to receive the above inputs and return a String "helloSwiftApple".
The returning String must "include" all input Strings without repetitions. For instance, the returning String can't be "hellohelloSwiftSwiApplele" How can I do this with Swift?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad explanation. Just got started studying algorithm using Swift.

Comment: How do you define what is a repetition ? For example why is `hello` and `helloSwift` the same ? Why is `Apple` and `le` the same ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a code writing service, so it tends to work best when you show what you've attempted first. You may want to check out [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @ShawnFrank Sorry for the bad explanation. I think "repetition" is not the word I was intending. 
"hello" and "helloSwift" is not the same. "hello" is included in "helloSwift", thus only adding "Swift". I was trying to say that the same string should not appear twice in the final result. Thanks in advances

Comment: @jnpdx Terribly sorry, this is my first time uploading a question on stackoverflow. I will try to be more clear next time. thanks for the advice

Comment: @mysticbenz - no worries. But to get best result, you should add some code of what you tried, then more people might help. One idea could be to go through strings one by one and see if current string is a subset of previous strings or previous strings are a subset of current string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a "brute force" approach, but it may work for you.

- split the string into an array `a` of unique "words"
- loop through the array `for i in 0..<a.count`

  - remove element i `word`
  - does any element in `a` contain `word`?
  - if NO

    - add `word` to new array
  - put `word` back in `a`
- return `newArray` joined into string

So, we can use this extension to remove duplicates from an array ([Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-remove-duplicate-items-from-an-array)):

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    func removingDuplicates() -> [Element] {
        var addedDict = [Element: Bool]()
        
        return filter {
            addedDict.updateValue(true, forKey: $0) == nil
        }
    }
    
    mutating func removeDuplicates() {
        self = self.removingDuplicates()
    }
}
```

and we can write a func like this:

```
func parseString(_ str: String) -> String {
    
    // split the string into an array of "words" (no spaces)
    var a1: [String] = str.components(separatedBy: " ").removingDuplicates()
    
    // an array to hold the unique words
    var a2: [String] = []
    
    // for each word
    for i in 0..<a1.count {
        // remove the word from the array
        let word = a1.remove(at: i)
        // filter the remaining array by elements containing word
        let n = a1.filter { $0.contains(word) }
        // if no elements contain word
        if n.count == 0 {
            // append it to array of unique words
            a2.append(word)
        }
        // put the word back into the full array
        a1.insert(word, at: i)
    }
    
    // change "-" to "" for no separators
    return a2.joined(separator: "-")
}
```

A quick test like this:

```
    let test: [String] = [
        "1 hello helloSwift Swi Apple le",
        "2 I want a string",
        "3 i want a string",
        "4 I want a function to receive the above inputs and return a String",
        "5 i want a function to receive the above inputs and return a String",
        "6 abc aBc Abc abc ABC aabc",
        "7 droid android otherdroid and android and otherdroid",
    ]

    test.forEach { s in
        let rs = parseString(s)
        print("Orig:", s)
        print("Ret :", rs)
        print()
    }
```

outputs this to the debug console:

```
Orig: 1 hello helloSwift Swi Apple le
Ret : 1-helloSwift-Apple

Orig: 2 I want a string
Ret : 2-I-want-string

Orig: 3 i want a string
Ret : 3-want-string

Orig: 4 I want a function to receive the above inputs and return a String
Ret : 4-I-want-function-to-receive-the-above-inputs-and-return-String

Orig: 5 i want a function to receive the above inputs and return a String
Ret : 5-want-function-to-receive-the-above-inputs-and-return-String

Orig: 6 abc aBc Abc abc ABC aabc
Ret : 6-aBc-Abc-ABC-aabc

Orig: 7 droid android otherdroid and android and otherdroid
Ret : 7-android-otherdroid
```

As you'll immediately notice, you didn't mention case-sensitivity, so we haven't addressed that... that's why examples 2 & 3 and 4 & 5 return different results:

- "I" ***is not*** found in "string"
- "i" ***is*** found in "string"

Comment: Wow thank u very much for the detailed explanation! This really helps me out!! It should have took a long time for you. I really appreciate it. Thanks a million!